# nextLine() not working after input of a double data type

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("");
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d=scan.nextDouble();
        String s=scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

**Input =:**
23
23
mks 
**output should be:-**

String:mks
Double:23.0
Int:23

But It is not taking String input and taking only the double and Int type.
Even not asking me for give the input to string type.
so,
**Input is :**

23
23
**output is :**
String :
double:23.0
Int:23

Comment: when you enter "23" the code recognises "23\n" internally. nextLine consumes the "\n" from the "23\n" string. you need to add another nextLine() to remove this dangling '\n'

Comment: Thank you , that works .